# Return specific array value field in aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a issue in MongoDB i'm trying to build a very complex aggregate query, and its work almost as i want it, but i still have trobles, and the problems is i need to move a spefiect field so i can use it later.

My aggregate look like this right now.

```
db.getCollection('travel_sights').aggregate([{
  '$match': {
    'preview.photo' : {
      '$exists':true
    },
    '_id': {
      '$in' : [ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7")]
    }
  }
},{
  '$unwind' : '$preview.photo'
}, {
  '$lookup':{
    'from' : 'media_data',
    'localField' : '_id',
    'foreignField':'bind',
    'as':'media'
  }   
}])
```

and it will return data like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7"),
    "preview" : {
        "photo" : {
            "id" : ObjectId("5b7affea1fbad441494a663b"),
            "sort" : 0
        }
    },
    "media" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7affea1fbad441494a663b")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b002d1fbad441494a663c")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b00351fbad441494a663d")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9baa1fbad410de638bbb")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bae1fbad410e10f32f9")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb11fbad441494a663e")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb41fbad4ff97273402")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb71fbad4ff99527e82")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbb1fbad410de638bbc")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbe1fbad410e10f32fa")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc11fbad441494a663f")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc41fbad4ff97273403")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc71fbad4ff99527e83")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bca1fbad410de638bbd")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bcd1fbad441494a6640")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bd01fbad4ff97273404")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7"),
    "preview" : {
        "photo" : {
            "id" : ObjectId("5b7b002d1fbad441494a663c"),
            "sort" : 0
        }
    },
    "media" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7affea1fbad441494a663b")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b002d1fbad441494a663c")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b00351fbad441494a663d")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9baa1fbad410de638bbb")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bae1fbad410e10f32f9")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb11fbad441494a663e")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb41fbad4ff97273402")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb71fbad4ff99527e82")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbb1fbad410de638bbc")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbe1fbad410e10f32fa")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc11fbad441494a663f")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc41fbad4ff97273403")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc71fbad4ff99527e83")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bca1fbad410de638bbd")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bcd1fbad441494a6640")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bd01fbad4ff97273404")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7"),
    "preview" : {
        "photo" : {
            "id" : ObjectId("5b7b00351fbad441494a663d"),
            "sort" : 0,
            "primary" : false
        }
    },
    "media" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7affea1fbad441494a663b")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b002d1fbad441494a663c")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b00351fbad441494a663d")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9baa1fbad410de638bbb")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bae1fbad410e10f32f9")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb11fbad441494a663e")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb41fbad4ff97273402")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb71fbad4ff99527e82")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbb1fbad410de638bbc")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbe1fbad410e10f32fa")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc11fbad441494a663f")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc41fbad4ff97273403")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc71fbad4ff99527e83")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bca1fbad410de638bbd")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bcd1fbad441494a6640")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bd01fbad4ff97273404")
        }
    ]
}
```

and what you can se the last data have `preview.photo.primary` on it, and this field i want to return when i'm done with my aggregate query.

My final query look like this:

```
db.getCollection('travel_sights').aggregate([{
  '$match': {
    'preview.photo' : {
      '$exists':true
    },
    '_id': {
      '$in' : [ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7")]
    }
  }
},{
  '$unwind' : '$preview.photo'
}, {
  '$lookup':{
    'from' : 'media_data',
    'localField' : '_id',
    'foreignField':'bind',
    'as':'media'
  }   
},{
  '$unwind':'$media'
},{
  '$project' : {
    'preview' : 1,
    'media': 1,
  }
}, {
  '$group': {
    '_id':'$media._id',
    'primary': {
      '$first':'$preview'
    }
  }   
}])
```

The problem here is when i want `$preview` return so i can find the primary about it, its allways only return the first where the value not exists, if i use `$push` the problem is i get every thing.

is there a way so i can pick the right primary value in my return? have trying `$addFields` to but whitout eny kind of lock.

**Travel_sights data:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7"),
    "city_id" : ObjectId("5b6d0cb6222d4c70b803eaeb"),
    "activated" : true,
    "deleted" : false,
    "url" : "url is here",
    "name" : "title of it here",
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2018-08-22T17:22:27.000Z"),
    "content" : "content here",
    "preview" : {
        "photo" : [ 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7affea1fbad441494a663b"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7b002d1fbad441494a663c"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7b00351fbad441494a663d"),
                "sort" : 0,
                "primary" : true
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9baa1fbad410de638bbb"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bae1fbad410e10f32f9"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb11fbad441494a663e"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb41fbad4ff97273402"),
                "sort" : 0,
                "primary" : false
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bb71fbad4ff99527e82"),
                "sort" : 0,
                "primary" : false
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbb1fbad410de638bbc"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bbe1fbad410e10f32fa"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc11fbad441494a663f"),
                "sort" : 0
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc41fbad4ff97273403"),
                "sort" : 0,
                "primary" : false
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bc71fbad4ff99527e83"),
                "sort" : 0,
                "primary" : false
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bca1fbad410de638bbd"),
                "sort" : 0,
                "primary" : false
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bcd1fbad441494a6640"),
                "sort" : 0,
                "primary" : false
            }, 
            {
                "id" : ObjectId("5b7d9bd01fbad4ff97273404"),
                "sort" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**3 sample foto bind data here:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7affea1fbad441494a663b"),
    "file-name" : "55575110311__0F115282-B5A0-4654-AA44-B7DC2C682992.jpeg",
    "options" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b6fb855222d4c70b8041093")
    ],
    "type" : "images",
    "files" : [ 
        {
            "width" : 70,
            "height" : 53
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 400,
            "height" : 300
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 800,
            "height" : 600
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 1600,
            "height" : 1200
        }
    ],
    "bind" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b002d1fbad441494a663c"),
    "file-name" : "55575110748__E7B07EFD-9F7E-40D6-8B57-38F708E4C0C0.jpeg",
    "options" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b6fb855222d4c70b8041093")
    ],
    "type" : "images",
    "files" : [ 
        {
            "width" : 70,
            "height" : 53
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 400,
            "height" : 300
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 800,
            "height" : 600
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 1600,
            "height" : 1200
        }
    ],
    "bind" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7")
    ],
    "description" : "this is secoudn demo!",
    "title" : "demo 3"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b7b00351fbad441494a663d"),
    "file-name" : "paris2.jpg",
    "options" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b6fb855222d4c70b8041093")
    ],
    "type" : "images",
    "files" : [ 
        {
            "width" : 70,
            "height" : 53
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 400,
            "height" : 300
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 800,
            "height" : 600
        }, 
        {
            "width" : 1600,
            "height" : 1200
        }
    ],
    "bind" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7")
    ],
    "description" : "this is a demo1 :)",
    "title" : "demo"
}
```

Comment: why you made a `$unwind` to `preview` at second stage of your first query?

Comment: i do this becure i need sort, primary values in my bind options (preview.photo.$.sort and preview.photo.$.primary) i don't know how else to get it later.

Comment: From here it seems to difficult what your are trying to do or achieve... It would be better if you post your initial sample collection and the output you want.

Comment: instead of `$unwind` `$preview.photo` add this to your second stage `{
    $addFields: {
      "preview.photo": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$preview.photo",
              as: "photo",
              cond: {
                $ne: [
                  "$$photo.primary",
                  undefined
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: very nice, never seen this before, can you explain with a awsner? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the element from the array where the `primary` field exists using [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation and then easily [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) with the `media._id` field and get the [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) document value.

Finally your query will be

```
db.getCollection("travel_sights").aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "preview.photo" : { "$exists":true },
    "_id": { "$in" : [ ObjectId("5b7af9701fbad410e10f32f7") ] }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "preview.photo": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$preview.photo",
          "as": "photo",
          "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$photo.primary", undefined ] }
        }}, 0
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$lookup":{
    "from" : "media_data",
    "localField" : "_id",
    "foreignField": "bind",
    "as": "media"
  }},
  { "$unwind":"$media" },
  { "$project" : { "preview" : 1, "media": 1, }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$media._id",
    "primary": { "$first": "$preview" }
  }}  
])
```

Comment: its wirdt, i still return false in it, i thought its return the resualt, but i toke wrong, i have add the main data + 3 sample of binding if its helping.

Comment: so do you want the result where `$preview.photo.primary` is equal to true??

Comment: i want the current value of $preview.photo.primary for each photo somtime its true, false or not exists

Comment: How do know current value for `$preview.photo.primary`... Is there any criteria ? please post your sample output as well

Comment: i'm $unwind before to split all $preview.photo up, and then i do $lookup to join $preview.photo.id with $media._id here i got my data, and group it last to only get it one time, and when i $unwind i can se id, sort and primary on every $preview.photo but when i later group its gone and can't get access to it agin.

Comment: i think i can fix my issue if i after the last $unwind on $media if i can make a match after this on preview.photo.id and $media._id and then remove $group i think its can fix the issue, but i can find a way to do this now.

Comment: This is what i want :)    {
        "$addFields": {
            "isPreviewMatchMedia": { "$cmp": [ "$media._id", "$preview.photo.id" ] }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "isPreviewMatchMedia": 0 } }

then i wan use $unwind on preview.photo and remove group by becures i get what i want this way, you push me to the right way, if you want to explain about this $cmp do, as first and keep the orther awser to, then i will accept you awsner :)

Comment: [`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/) compares two values and return the value -1, 1 and 0 if the value is less, greater and equal to the second value respectively... And you can edit my answer as well I will confirm then...

Comment: You can either accept this or answer to your own question